# Is it possible to programmatically cause dlopen() in OS X to return NULL?

Tags: c++, c, macos, dylib

Let's call it x.dylib. I only want x.dylib to be loaded sometimes.

In the initialization of the dylib is there any way to have some logic which would cause the dlopen() call that tried to load x.dylib to fail to load x.dylib and return NULL?

Renaming x.dylib is not an option.

I looked through http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-210.2.3/src/dyldAPIs.cpp but I am unfamiliar with the code.

I thought maybe this would do it:

```
__attribute__((constructor))                                                   
void initializer(void) {                                                       
    fprintf(stderr, "initializer\n");                                          
    throw;                                                                     
}
```

but when I call dlopen() on the dylib with that initializer, i just get "`initializer
terminate called without an active exceptionAbort trap: 6`"

So I'm stumped; any help would be great.

Edit:
The stack trace, when viewed with gdb is as follows:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff9128a82a in __kill ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff9128a82a in __kill ()
#1  0x00007fff93539a9c in abort ()
#2  0x00007fff987f07bc in abort_message ()
#3  0x00007fff987edfcf in default_terminate ()
#4  0x00007fff987ee001 in safe_handler_caller ()
#5  0x00007fff987ee05c in std::terminate ()
#6  0x00007fff987ef152 in __cxa_throw ()
#7  0x0000000100003eb5 in initializer ()
#8  0x00007fff5fc0fda6 in __dyld__ZN16ImageLoaderMachO18doModInitFunctionsERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextE ()
#9  0x00007fff5fc0faf2 in __dyld__ZN16ImageLoaderMachO16doInitializationERKN11ImageLoader11LinkContextE ()
#10 0x00007fff5fc0d2e4 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE ()
#11 0x00007fff5fc0d27d in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader23recursiveInitializationERKNS_11LinkContextEjRNS_21InitializerTimingListE ()
#12 0x00007fff5fc0e0b7 in __dyld__ZN11ImageLoader15runInitializersERKNS_11LinkContextERNS_21InitializerTimingListE ()
#13 0x00007fff5fc034dd in __dyld__ZN4dyld24initializeMainExecutableEv ()
#14 0x00007fff5fc0760b in __dyld__ZN4dyld5_mainEPK12macho_headermiPPKcS5_S5_ ()
#15 0x00007fff5fc01059 in __dyld__dyld_start ()
```

which come from:

- http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-210.2.3/src/dyld.cpp
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-210.2.3/src/ImageLoader.cpp
- http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-210.2.3/src/ImageLoaderMachO.cpp

I'm surprised that I don't see dlopen() in the stack trace though.

Comment: Try throwing a `const char*`, maybe? Looks at a glance like the dyld_open code only catches thrown things of type `const char*`.

Comment: The same message prints when I `throw s;`, where `s` is a const char*.

Comment: Hmm. If you use 'catch throw' in gdb, you can catch exceptions as they're thrown, which might give a more informative traceback.

Comment: That's like trying to write an executable that'll cause the system to report file not found when you try to execute it.  It doesn't make sense to want that.

Comment: There's no call to `dlopen()` involved here. The stack trace shows that dyld is loading the program and all of the libraries that it's linked against (and all of the libraries they are linked against, etc.) at launch. That's an entirely different thing than a call to `dlopen()`. `dlopen()` can fail gracefully. Failure to load a library on which the program depends (directly or indirectly) is a hard failure. If you managed to achieve it, it would just mean that loading of the program as a whole would fail, as it does if you remove or rename x.dylib so it's not found at all.